# Is there an alternate way to hold down a mouse button with AHK?

Tags: autohotkey

For holding down a mouse button, I've tried:

```
Click down
```

and

```
Send {LButton down}
```

But both of these methods cause the game I'm making a macro for to log me out for "too many actions". Are there any alternative methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mouseclick](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm)

Mouseclick, left, x, y, D

Comment: Good answer, tested it, which by the way it needs to be formatted as `Mouseclick, left, x, y, , , D` or it wont work - however, it had the same problem of too many actions.

Comment: Im going to accept and ask a different question because I think your answer is probably the only alternative way of clicking, the question I need to be asking is probably different.